# How to check if the stream has finished in this interprocess communication case (in C)?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, ipc

I'm writing code to interface with another program.

```
    FILE* streamout = fdopen(fdout[0],"r");
```

I have used like shown before fdopen to be able to handle the reading like reading from a file. 
The problem is I don't know what stop condition to use when trying to read from streamout in the following loop.

```
while(fgets(endbuffer,sizeof(endbuffer),streamout) != NULL)
        {
                strcat(buffer,endbuffer);
        }
```

The program never exits the while loop, even when the streaming has finished.

**Edit**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

//this function returns when it receives a particular response ie: imready    
void wait_until_ready(FILE *,FILE *);

int main(){

    int fdin[2];
    int fdout[2];

    pid_t pid;

    if ((pipe(fdin)<0)||(pipe(fdout)<0))
    {
        perror("pipe error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((pid = fork())<0)
    {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fdin[1]);
        close(fdout[0]);
        dup2(fdin[0],0);
        dup2(fdout[1],1);
        execlp("stockfish","stockfish",0);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fdin[0]);
        close(fdout[1]);
        FILE* streamin = fdopen(fdin[1],"w");
        FILE* streamout = fdopen(fdout[0],"r");
        char buffer[1024];
        wait_until_ready(streamin,streamout);
        fprintf(streamin,"position startpos\n");
        fprintf(streamin,"go\n");
        fflush(streamin);

        while (fgets(endbuffer,sizeof(endbuffer),streamout) != NULL)
        {
                strcat(buffer,endbuffer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did the sending process close the stream it is/was writing too?  Did all intermediate processes, or the one that started everything off, close the stream yet?  If you're not getting EOF, it means that some process still has the write file descriptor open.  Come to that, did this process make sure it closed the write file descriptor?

Comment: Why are you reading from a file named "streamout"?  You typically read input, and write output.  I would expect to see `FILE *streamout= fdopen(fd[1], "w")` and `FILE * streamin = fdopen(fd[0], "r")`, but `streamout = fdopen(fd[0], "r")` smells wrong.

Comment: Given the name `fdout[0]`, I am guessing you previously called `pipe(fdout)`.  Perhaps you forked a child which is writing to `fdout[1]`.  Probably you forgot to close `fdout[1]` in the process which is reading `fdout[0]`, though.  Tough to say without more details.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's right, there is a process with a write file descriptor open, and I didn't plan to close it, what I did is : I forked the processed changed the stdin and stdout of the child process than I exec'd to the program that I want to interface with, the communication between the two processes is as follow :                                                       parent process >>>> gives instruction >>>>>child process                          parent process <<<<< response <<<<<<<<<child process  and so on.

Comment: You'll never get EOF on the read end of a pipe while any process, even the current process, has the write end of the pipe open.  You must make sure you do your plumbing cleanly — no unwanted writers in particular; unwanted readers can be a problem too.  Your description of what you did is a little ambiguous.  Did you create two pipes, then fork, then the child used `dup2()` to connect appropriate pipe ends to standard input and output, and executed, while the parent arranged to read from the child (and write to the child?)?

Comment: @WilliamPursell that's why I did : FILE* stremout = fdopen(...etc  . yes I forked a child, changed stdin and stdout of the child process then exec'd to the program I want to interface with, will it be more clear if I included more of my code ?

Comment: **Rule of Thumb** If you use `dup()` or `dup2()` — or `fcntl()` if you're masochistic — to copy one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, you should close ***both*** ends of the original pipe.  (1 pipe, 1 dup2, 2 closes.) Using `fdopen()` to create streams is fine; use `freopen()` to copy a stream to standard input or standard output.  But you still need to follow the rules.  When your child execs another process, you don't need to create streams.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's exactly what I did

Comment: Time to point you to how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've not shown us enough code to be able to see what's going wrong.  There are many ways to do it wrong; a lot fewer ways to do it right.

Comment: for each process, I closed the descrptors that I didn't use

Comment: I believe you — your computer doesn't, though.  And since it's the computer you've got to persuade, you'd best show your code (as cleaned up as possible) so we can see why the computer is unpersuaded by your assertions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler check the edit

Answer (score 0):

I quoted a **Rule of Thumb** (quoted myself, AFAIK):

- If you use [`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) or [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) — or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) if you're masochistic — to copy one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, you should close ***both*** ends of the original pipe (1 × `pipe()`, 1 × `dup2()` ⇒ 2 × `close()`).

#### Child code

You claim you do that.  Your code shows you do not.  You have:

```
if (pid == 0)
{
    close(fdin[1]);
    close(fdout[0]);
    dup2(fdin[0],0);
    dup2(fdout[1],1);
    execlp("stockfish","stockfish",0);
}
```

You need:

```
if (pid == 0)
{
    dup2(fdin[0],0);
    dup2(fdout[1],1);
    close(fdin[0]);
    close(fdin[1]);
    close(fdout[0]);
    close(fdout[1]);
    execlp("stockfish","stockfish",0);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute 'stockfish'\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

If you don't do this, you can run into problems.  You can do some of the closes before the `dup2()` calls if you're careful (your original two `close()` calls were fine, but I grouped all four together in the modified version).  You can reorder the operations a fair amount as to which `close()` comes first and which second in each pair if you do them both after the `dup2()` calls.  You can do all the ops on one pipe before doing any on the other.  Etc.

Note that you should ensure you exit — or take other appropriate evasive action — if the `execlp()` fails.  It will happen, sooner or later, and typically leads to trouble.  There are those who'd argue for `_exit()` instead of `exit()`.  If you've flushed pending I/O before you `fork()`, there shouldn't be a problem.

#### Parent code

The parent code looks OK at first glance.  You are not using `dup2()` to standard input or standard output, so closing just the two unused ends of the pipes is fine.

You write a message to the child.  You … oh, you don't close the pipe to the child (`fclose(streamin);`) … so you write the message to the child, and you get a response back, but the child is now waiting for the next command from the parent, while the parent is waiting for more data from the child.  So they're at an impasse — both processes are waiting for the other to do something, and neither will do what the other needs, so they're in deadlock.

If you mean to write the single message to `stockfish`, then you need to call `fclose(streamin);` before going into the read loop.  If you need to send more messages, you have to know how you can tell that `stockfish` has finished the current message so you can break the loop and go back to send the next command.  That might be another line saying `imready` like the `wait_until_ready()` function looks for.  So you might need:

```
buffer[0] = '\0';   // Make sure that strcat() works sanely

while (fgets(endbuffer, sizeof(endbuffer), streamout) != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp(endbuffer, "imready\n") == 0)
        break;
    // check for buffer overflow, etc before blithely appending!
    // this is not efficient; it is sufficient, though.
    if (strlen(buffer) + strlen(endbuffer) + 1 >= sizeof(buffer))
        break;
    strcat(buffer, endbuffer);
}
```

Comment: I thought that dup2 would close the descriptor, that's why I didn't close it.      I was doing like you suggested, I thought there was a better way to handle it that I am missing. Thank you for taking time to give me these details.